# How can I tell if there is an instrumentation of address sanitizer?

Tags: llvm, address-sanitizer

I tried to add address sanitizer by -fsanitize=address during the build phase. Now I want to find the basic blocks from the executable for asan to instrument. Can I determine whether the current basic block is instrumented by asan by calling functions such as _*asan** within the basic block? Or the instrumentation of asan by identifying the function that is replaced with _*intercepotor*? Here is an example.

The source code:

```
using namespace std;
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
     int* array = new int[100];
     int res = array[100];
     delete [] array;
     return res;
 }
```

compile without -fsanitize=address:
[image]

compile with -fsanitize=address:
[image]